# Firefox browser cannot restore page when navigated back in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver with Firefox .

driver.navigate().back();

I  browse through  pages and when I navigate back through page , I get following exception.In Browser it says Document expired.

org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 23 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.21.0', revision: '16552', time: '2012-04-11 19:09:00'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_20'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:175)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:459)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:245)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getText(RemoteWebElement.java:141)
    at run.DriverImpl.startScrapingFromThePage(DriverImpl.java:48)
    at ui.SAFSPUserInterface.startButtonClicked(SAFSPUserInterface.java:311)
    at ui.SAFSPUserInterface$1.actionPerformed(SAFSPUserInterface.java:62)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6263)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)

The page contains Ajax and javascript calls . Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Is this the second it clicks the back button or is it when it clicks the back button and then goes on to try and find the element?

Comment: when it clicks back button, there is no page present. Browser shows "Document expired".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the exception you pasted is not related to navigating back. You have a handle to a stale element causing the exception. StaleElementException occurs when you have a WebElement reference to a HTML element in the page which may have been removed/lost due to interactions on the page. So your WebElement which is a proxy to the non-existant DOM element is invalid.

There is also this [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3611) in webdriver when navigating back to pages originally loaded via POST request. So the page you are expecting may not have actually loaded. Soution to postback warning in firefox is to reissue navigate().back(), i.e. backout twice.